# Trying to view sheet after opening spreadsheet with openById() in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a Google Sheets that has D3.JS, i'm trying to use a specific sheet in the spreadsheet file, since that's where the table is located for the graph i'm trying to show. So far, the openById works but still is unable to locate the specific sheet in the spreadsheet.

```
function getChartData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("some id");
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var headings = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
     .map(function(heading) {
       return heading.toLowerCase();
     });
  ...
}
```

EDIT: I've tried the following code changes below:

```
function getChartData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("some id");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Tracker1");

  // new code above
  var headings = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
      .map(function(heading) {
        return heading.toLowerCase();
      });
  Logger.log(headings);

  var values = sheet.getRange(3, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-2, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
      obj[headings[j]] = values[i][j];
    }
    data.push(obj);
  }

  return data;
}
```

EDIT 10/2/18 11:00 PM : I'm still getting `null`, no error messages, no chart showing in app. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, even without having `getActiveSheet();`

Comment: You want to retrieve the sheets except for 1st sheet. If my understanding is correct, are [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename) and [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets) useful for your situation? If you cannot understand about how to use them, please tell me.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use it. But I at least tried getSheetByName(name) with the following:                                                                                                            
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Tracker1");

Comment: I think that your snippet is correct. If there are some issues, please provide the error messages and your latest script. If you can do, please add them to your question using Edit button. By this, it will help users think of your solution.

Comment: Ive tested the app, i'm not seeing any error messages, this is the script, i've also updated question with the full code https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx4lOFzFdyb5zytvKcVvwnUfQBLE_n5WxILbaBvff42RAKdbH0/exec @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for your response. In your question, you want to use the sheet of ``Tracker1`` from the spreadsheet with the file ID of ``1u20LdE_UzYi8ehIQAOfrwPq2TBjtnecsJVETC3iWOs``. I understand like this. From your script in your updated question, I think that ``var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Tracker1")`` works, if the sheet name of ``Tracker1`` is existing in the spreadsheet.

Comment: https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/d3-google-sheets/ this is the tutorial i used, @Tanaike I am getting an outline of a chart... maybe I did something right?

Comment: is the file ID from the URL from the sheet itself (opening the file from google sheets) or from the URL from the published sheet (the URL given after you publish the sheet)? @Tanaike

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? In your question, you want to use the sheet of Tracker1 from the spreadsheet with the file ID of ``1u20LdE_UzYi8ehIQAOfrwPq2TBjtnecsJVETC3iWOs``. I understand like this. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: right, i wasn't sure if the file ID was correct. Tanaike

Comment: Don't forget that you cannot send `Date` objects from server to client. You must serialize dates (to string or milliseconds) before returning them from a `google.script.run` call. This is explicitly stated in documentation.

Comment: If you are getting an error message, make sure you include the error message text *in full* in your question. If you have done debugging (sounds like you have) and have `null` for something that you feel should not be null, please clarify exactly what is going on. **Where** are you "getting null"? What "chart" are you talking about? What "app"?